# Duplicate column name in spark read csv

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I read csv file, which has a duplicate column.

I want to preserve the name of the column in dataframe.

I tried to add this option in my sparkcontext conf **spark.sql.caseSensitive** and put it **true** , but unfortunately it has no effect.

The duplicate column name is NU_CPTE. Spark tried to rename it by adding number of column 0, 7

**NU_CPTE0|CD_EVT_FINANCIER|TYP_MVT_ELTR|DT_OPERN_CLI|LI_MVT_ELTR|    MT_OPERN_FINC|FLSENS|NU_CPTE7**

```
SparkSession spark= SparkSession
                .builder()
                .master("local[2]")
                .appName("Application Test")
                .getOrCreate();    

spark.sparkContext().getConf().set("spark.sql.caseSensitive","true"); 

Dataset<Row> df=spark.read().option("header","true").option("delimiter",";").csv("FILE_201701.csv");

df.show(10);
```

I want something like this as result:

**NU_CPTE|CD_EVT_FINANCIER|TYP_MVT_ELTR|DT_OPERN_CLI|LI_MVT_ELTR|    MT_OPERN_FINC|FLSENS|NU_CPTE**

Answer (score 1):

Spark is fixed to allow the duplicate column names with the number appended. Hence you are getting the numbers appended to the duplicate column names. Please find the below link

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16896

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to set the caseSensitive property will indeed be ineffective. Try replacing:

```
spark.sparkContext().getConf().set("spark.sql.caseSensitive","true");
```

with:

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true");
```

However, this still assumes your original columns have some sort of difference in casing. If they have the same casing, they will still be identical and will be suffixed with the column number.